# PagerSlidingTabStrip: ViewPager badge numbers

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm able to put badge numbers on `Button`s, etc. but is there any example of how badge number can be placed on a view pager? For button I'm creating an xml with the proper background resource, etc. but i'm not able to find any way to place it on the `PagerSlidingTabStrip`.

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/badge"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

I set the value to `gone` first and show when needed. Is there a way to do this with the view pager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do a small modification into the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` .

Insert this piece of code into the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` class:

```
public LinearLayout getTabsContainer(){
return tabsContainer;
}
```

Now you are able to access the tabs views by :

`View currentTabView = pagerSlidingTabStrip.getTabsContainer().getChildAt(currentPosition);`

You can easily use the **https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger** , follow the example below:

**In the MainActivity**:

`public static View currentTab;`

`private PagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip;`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            currentTab = pagerSlidingTabStrip.getTabsContainer().getChildAt(0);
            return firstFragment;
        case 1:
             currentTab = pagerSlidingTabStrip.getTabsContainer().getChildAt(1);
             return secondFragment;
        case 2:
             currentTab = pagerSlidingTabStrip.getTabsContainer().getChildAt(2);
             return thirdFragment; 
       } 
        return null;
}
```

**In the Fragments**:

```
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(getActivity(), MainActivity.currentTab);
badge.setText("1"); //Whatever value you should add
badge.show();
```

Comment: Just tried it. It adds the badge but removes the tab icon in that place form `pagerSlidingTabStrip` . Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: @AdeelAhmad Can you please tell how to edit that file. I'm using android studio and as the file is inside jar i'm unable to edit the file and put that function in it

Comment: @satyapol Im not sure about android studio. If nothing works you could copy/paste the code for PagerSlidingTabStrip.java, into a new class in your own package and make changes in it.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad I'm getting error as cannot resolve symbol badge.setText(). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Renan's solution is correct but it removes the tab icon if app:pstsShouldExpand="true" in your xml. The solution is changing "expandedTabLayoutParams" parameter in PagerSlidingTabStrip.java as the following :

```html
expandedTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
```