# Viewpager and badgeview

Tags: android

I want to use this badge library in my tabs : https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger It's looks simple.

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

And my tab system is:https://stackoverflow.com/a/26179583/4014703 How can I get target view for 2nd tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076422/3977935) answer I was able to add a badge like this

```
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(getActivity(), tabs.getTabsContainer().getChildAt(3));
badge.setText("1"); //Whatever value you should add
badge.show();
```

But unfortunately instead of showing a badge on top of the icon/text, the badge replaces it in the `pagerSliderTabStrip`